# how multiple (LP)pairs of a token works, for pricing?

Tags: blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, pancakeswap

I am working on a token to launch on BSC and we want this token to be traded in multiple pairs
For Example :
Token Name : GAME
Token Pair 1 : GAME/USDT
Token Pair 2 : GAME/WBNB
Token Pair 3 : GAME/ETH
So now, we have created these pairs on Pancake and Added Liquidity, each pair is an LP Token and they work independently,
Problem # 1: They have different liquidity , but we added as per current Value of WBNB & ETH against USDT at the time of adding liquidity.
e.g :
GAME/USDT , 100,000 GAME & 100 USDT
GAME/BNB  , 100,000 GAME & 5 BNB (where 5 BNB equivalent to 1000 USDT)
same for GAME/ETH

When we trade on any of three pairs every pool show different value of reserves which is valid, where as WBNB & ETH price keep moving up and down against USDT as one example,
but what we want is to get avg. price of all traded Pairs as aggregated price , and for every different pairs that is traded must be on avg. price aggregated price or some thing like that.

suggest us what to do regarding that, any example or tutorial will be helpfull and guide us how price oracle can help or anything, i will be thankfull.

This is what i am trying to acheive,

when a person come to buy GAME token by USDT
Case 1 :
Quote : GAME/USDT = (LP1.GAME + LP2.GAME + LP3.GAME) / (LP1.USDT + LP2.WBNB~USDT + LP3.ETH~USDT)

this should be quote price for GAME/USDT case

Case 2 :
Quote : GAME/WBNB = (LP1.GAME + LP2.GAME + LP3.GAME) / (LP1.USDT~WBNB + LP2.WBNB + LP3.ETH~BNB)

this should be quote price for GAME/WBNB case